# KOMA-Script: How to left-align table/figure numbers in LoF/LoT

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, koma-script

I use KOMA-Script's `scrartcl` and the lists of tables and figures show a strange default behaviour: the figure/table numbers are either indented to the right or are all right-aligned with a large reserved width. Either way, as it is I find it ugly and don't understand the reasoning behind it. The table of contents just above is perfectly left-aligned by default.

How could I change the numbers to be left aligned at the left margin, as my second screenshot shows? I couldn't figure it out from the KOMA-Script manual.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\section{Section}
\subsection{SubSection}
\begin{figure}\caption{Testfigure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{Testtable}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

What this produces:
[image: what I get]

---

What I want:
[image: what I want]

Comment: Try `listof=flat`.

Comment: @ Johannes_B: This doesn't affect LoF or LoT. I tested it just now.

Comment: See the edit above.